# Importing packages from a local sub-directory

Tags: go, build, go-build

I'm new to go, so I hope this isn't perceived as dumb!

My current folder structure looks similar to this
[image]

In the `models` folder, I have `person.go`.

```
package models

//Person struct
type Person struct {
    Name   string
    Age    int
    Gender string
}
```

In the `main.go`, I like to import `models`, so that I can use the `person` struct.

```
    package main

import "fmt"
import "models"

func main() {
    person = Person{Name: "Ali", Age: 34, Gender: "Male"}    
    fmt.Println("person is", person)
}
```

When I try execute `go build`, I get the following exception:

> main.go:4:8: cannot find package "models" in any of:
>           C:\Go\src\models (from $GOROOT)
>           C:\Users\Ali\go\src\models (from $GOPATH)

I get that because my current working folder isn't my `$GOROOT`, nor is it the `$GOPATH`. In fact, I don't really want to add the `models` folder to either of those folders.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Just stick to what How to Write Go Code tells you. There is no need to deviate from that.

Answer (score -1):

Use `./models` instead of `models`.

But the better solution is using go project directory structure.

Read [official docs](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. but, thanks for the go's document. I'll take it from here.

Comment: Do not use relative paths for imports.